# Importing Nagios hosts to Icinga2?

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, nagios, icinga2

I have and old Nagios instance from Ubuntu 18.04 and wondering if I can import the config into Icinga2 somehow? I have Director installed but I don't really see an import feature.

I found some docs yesterday (https://icinga.com/docs/icinga-2/latest/doc/04-configuration/) and tried adding some host objects by hand into /etc/icinga2/conf.d/hosts.conf but spent 30 mins trying to chase down some weird characters in the whitespace that Icinga said was an unexpected carriage return.

Anyone have some tips on importing nagios hosts, services, etc into Icinga? Seems like it should be a cinch.

Comment: https://icinga.com/docs/icinga-2/latest/doc/23-migrating-from-icinga-1x/

Comment: Thanks. This got me on the right track.